# Convert Func<T1,bool> to Func<T2,bool>

Tags: c#, func

I have a DTO's and POCO's, and i use `Func<T,bool>` for "where". DTO and POCO entities have the identical properties (name and type of property).

I have managed to convert - translate DTO Expressions to POCO expressions using ExpresionsVisitor class.

I use expressions to include related entities (entity.Include) and Func as where.

There is a code example bellow, and i need help on implementing **Translate** method.

How can i do this?

```
public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ADTO a = new ADTO
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Test"
            };

            Func<ADTO,bool> dtoFunc = (dto => dto.Id == 1);

            Func<A, bool> func = Translate(dtoFunc);
        }

        private static Func<A, bool> Translate(Func<ADTO, bool> dtoFunc)
        {
            // Implementation here
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class A
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public String Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class ADTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public String Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Change `public class ADTO` to `public class ADTO : A` and you're done ;) Can you in any way convert A to ADTO? (I mean so that you don't need to manualy reassign values from one to another) implicit or explicit cast supported?

Comment: Why don't you just copy the properties? Seems trivial. There must be a reason you can't do that.

Comment: @AleksandarToplek DTOs in this example are Service Contracts and POCO's are my EF classes. This transformation is executed in separate layer. There is no direct connection between EF classes and contracts. Job is done in this specialized layer.

Comment: And why are you separating them? As I can remember those classes are partial so that you can add custom methods and properties to them... EDIT: ahh I misundestood. ok I see the problem

Comment: If you are are working with EF shouldn't you be using `Expression<Func<ADTO, bool>>`?

Comment: Ok, here's how I would do it then: For each entity class create new partial class and add cast operator to it so that you can simply call `(A)dtoObj`. Cast operator then manually copy values from given to new object.

Comment: Why in question you talk about Expresion, but in code use compiled functions?

Comment: @usr I've tried to get which property is used in predicate, but without result. How can i get properties from predicate? If i could get them, Name of property for example, i would create same properties for A class using reflection.

Comment: What about `a => dtoFunc(new ADTO() { Name = a.Name, ... })`?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain : Yes, i am working with EF. I know it could be done by expression, but i wanted to use Func explicitly for WHERE in my generic DAL. So my generic method in DAL would look like IList<T> GetSpecific(params Expression... navigation, Fun<T,bool> where)

Comment: @Olinad note, that the generic repository is an anti pattern: https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en#complete=1&hl=en&q=generic+repository+antipattern

Comment: @Grundy : Because i want to separate Expression<Func<T,object>> and Func<T,bool> in my project and use them for different things. See my previous comment.

Comment: @Olinad you can work with `Expressions` and compile it to `Func` when you need

Comment: @Grundy : I want to avoid using Expression as my method input. But if my question does not have answer, eventually i will.

Answer (score 2):

You can't "translate" a function. You need to implement it because of the strong typing.
What you need is a translator for ADTO into A, which is trivial:

```
private A Translate(ADTO adto)
{
    return new A() { Id = adto.Id, Name = adto.Name);
}
```

Then you need to understand what you are actually doing. The "function" is an execution upon data, it is not data itself. So you need two implementations, but they are identical:

```
Func<A, bool> funcA = (a => a.Id == 1);
Func<ADTO, bool> funcADTO = (adto => adto.Id == 1);
```

Next, you need to unify them. This is the real culprit. What you need is to tell the compiler who is who, choose one of these cases (just one, not all of them):

```
A extends ADTO
ADTO extends A
A extends AbstractDataTransferObject, ADTO extends AbstractDataTransferObject
A implements IDataTransferObject, ADTO implements IDataTransferObject
```

What I would advise is to go for the abstract version, it has several advantages.
At that point you can do this:

```
Func<AbstractDataTransferObject, bool> f = (adto => adto.Id == 1);
```

And use one function implementation for all derivatives, A and ADTO included.

Obviously, the abstract version will contain the common properties, that is ALL you have shown: Id and Name. I understand you'll have an awful lot more properties and types in a real world application.

What you really want is to abstract away the DTO functionality from the payload so you can implement a generic repository. That's what I've done years ago, at least. The problem later on is injecting lambdas to filter data independently of the derived type, but it is possible.

Sooner or later you'll see that you will have to understand very (VERY) well these arguments: [covariance and contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx)

I can give you a little more help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx

---

EDIT 2:

To reply to the comment how I implemented CRUD: I didn't.

CRUD is a concept of DAO, just as DTO is. In my code, I used the repository pattern and unit of work, which are a generalization and do without a facade.

This is a quick link to explain the difference: http://thinkinginobjects.com/2012/08/26/dont-use-dao-use-repository/

The repository is used this way:

```
public List<Customer> GetOlderThan(int minimumAge, bool lazy)
{
    using(Repository<Customer> repo = RepositoryFactory.Create<Customer>(lazy))
    {
        return repo.Retrieve(c => c.Age >= minimumAge);
    }
}
```

As you can see in 3 lines you can implement a query that is translated into SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Age >= @minimumAge;
```

The *final* problem when implementing a generic repository is the injection of the filter predicate. A pointer to the solution is that the predicate really is something like this:

```
Func<bool, T>
```

Where T is the actual entity type (e.g. `Customer`). To query customers it will be:

```
Func<bool, Customer>
```

The generic repository will then be:

```
Repository<Customer>
```

That said, implementing the `Repository<T>` is a blood bath because you need to derive all entities from a unique class (`AbstractDomainObject` in my case) and it has to be *compatible* with the actual Entity Framework.

The `AbstractDomainObject` is pretty much the same you wrote:

```
public abstract class AbstractDomainObject
{
    private int _id = -1;
    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            if (_id == -1)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("domain object not yet persisted");
            }

            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_id != -1)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("domain object already persisted");
            }

            _id = value;
        }
    }

    public bool IsPersisted
    {
        get
        {
            return _id != -1;
        }
    }
}
```

At some point, covariance and contravariance gets really complex when you have the `AbstractFactory`, `Repository<T>` and `AbstractDomainObject`.

Comment: Yes. you understood what i want. I already have abstract transfer class that defines behaviour and Facade interface in my transfer layer exposed to wcf layer - CRUD operations. If i understood you correctly, i cannot have generic Func translator? I must have have a specialized ,,where'' function implementation on both sides? E.g. GetAllById, GetAllByName in my Facade interf? Could you be more specific on how you did this in your project?

Comment: Nice approach. But i have to do this way. My generic data application layer is more like this: http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/05/30/generic-dal-using-entity-framework/.